# jquery resizable cursor help

Tags: jquery, user-interface, cursor, resizable

I have setup a div that is resizable:

```
$("mydiv").resizable();
```

Now when you go to resize it to the right the cursor goes off the the actual resize part. So if the cursor hits the side of the screen you have to let go of the mouse and go back and start resizing it again if you want to make it bigger. I know that with the draggable's there is an option for cursorAt that will tell the cursor to stay on that div. I looked at jquery ui.com but didnt see a cursorAt for the resizable. Is there a way to keep the mouse cursor on the resizable part while resizing?

Comment: Do not quite understand the problem. With reference to the UI/Resizable demo at http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/ , is that not the standard behaviour you want?

Comment: yes that is what I want but for some reason my cursor is not staying on the resize part like the one on the jquery demo.

Comment: I think I may have found the problem. I think that it is caused by the alsoResize function that I am calling. I am resizing another div when I am resizing this div but I didnt actually make that one resizable. I do not want it to be resizable by itself only if someone resizes the one I allow. Any suggestions? i will go back and accept some answers too. I completely forgot about it.

Comment: could be wrong. i just tried making that one resizable before the call to alsoResize but it seems to have the same effect.

Comment: Ok so I figured out the definite cause of the issue. It is because the other div that I am resizing has the property margin:0 auto. if I remove the auto it works fine. It seems that the auto property is killing it. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I see, the culprit seems to be what you pointed out:

"It is because the other div that I am resizing has the property `margin:0 auto`"

Having `0 auto` means the left, right margin is automatically adjusted to balance out which will centralise the `div` element. I do not think you want to resize in that manner as the position of the `div` moves while you are resizing in order to stay centered.

My suggestion, remove the `auto` setting for your margin.

**Update:**
I ran this in firebug at the [resizble demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/):
`$("#resizable").css("margin","0 auto");` to center the box using `auto` margin

Here's a screenshot of what I've got:
[image: resizable]

The resizing cursor moved away from the box's corner the more you drag away from the orginal size.

However it still work though the 'experience' feels odd.

Comment: I cant remove the auto setting for my margin. That is what centers that element so by removing the auto setting it makes my page no longer view correctly. Is there a way I can still center that element but make the cursor stay there?

Comment: @ngreenwood6: Check out my 'experiment' in my updated post. Resizing a centered box still works, though not very well. You can try it yourself on the demo page and compare with your own.

Comment: CSS is a pain in centralizing things, we need a `align: center center;`